# In ConstraintLayout when I set a layoutDirection of a view to "rtl" some thing go wrong. How to avoid this?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

my ***sample xml*** file to introduce my problem is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toBeUpdated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/update_text_view"
        android:onClick="updateTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="274dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want my (toBeUpdated) textView to have "rtl" layoutDirection. With this code we have above every thing is ok until the time textView must be updated. After (for any reason) I update this textView at run time the view jump to the left of the Guideline. I found what's wrong. The reason behind this sudden jump is that when direction is right to left so **right** is the start and **left** is the end of view (as you know completely reverse of usual). So my new and corrected version of this xml file to solve this issue is
***new version of xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toBeUpdated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/update_text_view"
        android:onClick="updateTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="274dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

in this version, at first, textView is in wrong place but after it is updated, it jump where I want. Completely reverse of first situation where the textView was in correct place until It was not updated and after that, jump happens.
In both cases a sudden unwanted jump happen. It may overlaps some other view or be overlapped by them.
And the most important thing is that maybe I don't want it to be updated even one time and that is an static title. What shall I do?
Is this a Bug or something?

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.testconstraintlayout"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your minSdkVersion please?

Comment: how long the text is, The text you trying to put in there dynamically?

Comment: It's not important. think whenever it is 0 I want it to be 1 and vice versa. @RezaHamzehie

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find more elegant solution that still uses start/end instead of right/left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why the text view should jump when the contents are updated. I think that this is a bug and that it is probably related to left/right and start/end confusion that crops up now and again.

You don't show screen shots and I can't be sure of what you are trying to achieve, but I think a work-around for you is to use left/right instead of start/end for the text view as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toBeUpdated"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I have tried this out and the view does not jump as it does with start/end.

Comment: However your solution worked well for me. but the jump maintain mysterious.Thanks

Comment: @MohammadRezaHosseini Not so mysterious. Start/end is preferred to left/right but bugs slip in when both are permitted. I think this is a bug and, if you are so inclined, should be reported to the Google team if it hasn't already.

Comment: @cheticamp, you made my day..